# Creating own applicationIDs

Tags: java, install4j

We created lots of installers using install4j. Now our DevOps think of reorganizing the application Ids. Today they are all created by the IDE. But DevOps want to give them structure.
Something like:

```
Product 1:
FIRM-PROD1-APPL-0102

Product 2:
FIRM-PROD2-SERV-0991
```

Is that supported throughout Install4j? IDE, Compiler, Registry, Update-mechanisms, ...

Has anyone tried that yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application ID is just a unique string, you can give it any structure you like.

However, when you change the application ID for an existing product, the previous installation directory will not be found anymore and by default, the installer will refuse to install into a directory with a different application ID.

You can work around both issues:

1. In a "Run script" action in the "Startup" node, execute the code
       ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo[] applicationInfos =
           ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById("");

   ```
   if (applicationInfos.length > 1) {
       context.setInstallationDirectory(applicationInfos[0].getInstallationDirectory());
   }

   return true;
   ```

   to find the previous installation directory for the old ID.
2. Deselecting the "Validate application id" property of the "Install files" action allows updates into a directory where a different application ID is installed.